# How to get total size of folder

Tags: solaris

In Solaris server how can i get total size of this output? Could you help me? I need to learn total size of last 1 day file

```
root@test:# find . -mtime -1 -type f | xargs du -sh
226M    ./10/01.tar
209M    ./10/02.tar
198M    ./10/03.tar
202M    ./10/04.tar
193M    ./10/05.tar
193M    ./10/06.tar
193M    ./10/07.tar
204M    ./10/08.tar
222M    ./10/09.tar
244M    ./10/10.tar
24G     ./10/00.tar
17G     ./10/01.tar
11G     ./10/02.tar
8.3G    ./10/03.tar
6.5G    ./10/04.tar
5.8G    ./10/05.tar
6.0G    ./10/06.tar
8.3G    ./10/07.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like can do the work:

```
 find . -mtime -1 -type f | xargs du -sk|awk '{a+=$1} END {print a}'
```

Solaris `du` do not have `--bytes` so you will get the result with precision of kibibytes. If you want it in gibibytes print the value of `a` divided by `1024*1024`

Comment: Thanks thats work! Really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-c` option to get the `c`umulated disk usage of the arguments with a `total` line at the end. So here:

```
zsh -c 'du -hsc -- **/*(DoN.m-1) | tail -n 1'
```

Here using `zsh` instead of `find -exec cmd {} +` (itself much better than that very unreliable `find | xargs`) to avoid the splitting of the list of files into multiple invocations of `du`. That means however that you may run into the limit on the maximum number of arguments that may be passed to a command upon execution.

If you have access to the GNU implementation of `du` (maybe called `gdu` on your system), you can also do:

```
find . -type f -mtime -1 -print0 | gdu --files0-from=- -hsc | tail -n 1
```

Or with the GNU implementation of `find`, to get the sum in kibibytes (but not deduplicated if there are hard links):

```
gfind . -type f -mtime -1 -printf '%k\n' |
  awk '{s+=$1}; END{print s+0}'
```

Comment: Thanks mate for reply! Really appreciated